# Fetch date data from list of objects in java using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

**This is my controller class**

```
 public Object getDashboardUser(@RequestParam ("state") String state,@RequestParam("startDate") String startDate,
                                       @RequestHeader(GradebookConstants.AUTHORIZATION) String token){
            try {
                var query = new FindDashboardUser();
                 query.setState(state);
                 query.setStartDate(startDate);
                var response = queryGateway.query(query, ResponseTypes.instanceOf(Object.class)).join();
    
                if (response == null){
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
                }
                return response;
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                logger.info(ex.getMessage());
                var safeErrorMessage = GradebookConstants.FAILED_TO_GET_BY_ID;
                return new ResponseEntity<>(safeErrorMessage, 
                   HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
    
        }
```

**This is my implementation class, here i want to fetch data by date, so that if startDate is equal to my widget class(createdDate), it fetches just that record, if it not matches then it return all the data from user object.**

```
@QueryHandler
    @Override
    public Object getDashboardUser(FindDashboardUser query) {

        List<WidgetData> widget = new ArrayList<WidgetData>();
        widget.add(new WidgetData("1", "Needs Grading User", 1, "0988-884884-144a","10-18-2022"));
        widget.add(new WidgetData("4", "Needs Grading User", 3, "0988-884884-244b","10-17-2022"));
        widget.add(new WidgetData("3", "Needs Grading User", 5, "0988-884884-344c","10-19-2022"));
        widget.add(new WidgetData("5", "Needs Grading User", 4, "0988-884884-444d","10-20-2022"));
        widget.add(new WidgetData("2", "Needs Grading User", 2, "0988-884884-544e","10-21-2022"));

        List<DashboardUserResponseDto> user = new ArrayList<DashboardUserResponseDto>();
        user.add(new DashboardUserResponseDto("0988-884884-344", "User Dashboard Widget", "Custom 
        Widget", widget));

        Collections.sort(widget, (id1, id2) -> (id2.getWidgetId().compareTo(id1.getWidgetId())));


         Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
         for (WidgetData widgetData : widget.toArray(new WidgetData[0]));

        return user;
    }
```

**This is widget class**

```
public class WidgetData {
    private String widgetId;
    private String widgetName;
    private Integer sequence;
    private String userId;
    private String createdDate;
}
```

**This is my DashboardUserResponseDto**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DashboardUserResponseDto {
    private String userId;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<WidgetData> widgetDetails;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Why not just iterate through the widgets, check the date and if you found one just return that otherwise return all? You might want to read [ask] and elaborate.

Comment: Btw, `(id1, id2) -> (id2.getWidgetId().compareTo(id1.getWidgetId())` could be written as `Comparator.comparing(WidgetData::getWidgetId)` or `Comparator.comparing(w -> w.getWidgetId())`. - Also `for (WidgetData widgetData : widget.toArray(new WidgetData[0]));` doesn't do anything and if you'd want to iterate then `for (WidgetData widgetData : widget)` would be sufficient as `widget` is a `List<WidgetData>`.

Comment: Yes, i want to iterate through it to check that if startDate becomes equal to widget createdDate, craetedDate is dummy data , i cant understand the logic how to compare it and get the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having in understanding. If you have the required date as a string in the same format your date data has (or better convert everything to `LocalDate`) then just iterate, compare the dates (use `equals()` or `compareTo()`) and if the condition is true collect the element into a list. Finally check if the list has some elements and if so return it. If not, return the user data you've mentioned.

Comment: Btw, if you have trouble iterating over a list and comparing element data you seem to be a beginner and should not be working on complex topics like rest controllers etc. just yet.

Comment: Yes, i am beginner and i have trouble iterating through over list and comparing date element.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest grabbing a Java tutorial and working through it. I already explained the basic approach above, let me add some simple sample code based on your's: `for( WidgetData w : widget) { if(query.getStartDate().equals(w.getCreatedDate()) { /*match found, do whatever you want with it*/ }}`. - I'll reiterate though: if you're such a beginner, start with basic tutorials and code instead of diving head first into complex topics such as controllers,  database access, etc. You will save yourself a lot of headaches.